# How to format private key (tool)?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My application generates private keys using PHP's openssl. Anyway, the key is presented to the user via ajax (which is not the question here). The issue is that the format becomes distorted when I display it on the page.

If `console.log(private_key)` where private_key is what came back from ajax call, the console displays this beautiful key:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICdQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAl8wggJbAgEAAoGBALXrNG1e/lENOtdn
RX3amQOnhr6KerEXnx86J5txnorGQIZ9lrvSh1Ch7MuqKcZ0oIna8M/MMqZIuLkO
oiMir1PsDPS1o+7KYd6g55gSluXCEoKaz9BMYdAqCL/T0B+fNJanwt662MHeSOcS
uEgpvMtJIs6ZQEIgWcv6M2ogfAGXAgMBAAECgYAdXYlJ+mKNDNipurbh+O5oQ5uh
mFLz0T9TWBzan72a4yO5Uf6J9RL4thq2SZKSwXLErf3fXTPz2ZtP7AfKKigo2ymU
YXkVQBjxxCPvPZaET5EjTStOh7wkXYjkKCjjYhL/alpLB8gK1sQwLEe7oYqw+GrK
wsuJKXbMDfc9cgYw8QJBAN0mGKARS75wLZ/tfXMeFXZRAMx0aRtVhEV/5C9raXZX
FNTMAMUl4UvlxZhV1quszs1aAv52jf32NDkg0fj2Dq8CQQDSlm8ExH5IwE4HQHDh
GuynrTUWk3R5zD1VMso97yoY7uTvKb991wPuV6NFAQuC/cCKTzdAU0Z9O44nKR0S
jTWZAkAcLt60h3+/pUwrNXjnUs4pZelUJQHAGgXhVYse//FQw4hEFjuC5HDx2zZz
U30oI723LeFzzGgMFXRSU3xu3ezBAkAyf+i3l/dAsv0DOCzZjn9Z5mtosoun+ZZr
q/Zby9KokAFOaRCGuN00dsescIe2LevSPxTc1Bt/RJzePzm9jSdhAkBQiQFjt4bD
y+qDP6T8DAaQqX5UuuNbjnQB5zLQ+ak39bMcc5vQW4oy5UPFeOvXFsrcjrllQkvc
+JG7x4bgHAU2
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

But when I want to show the user their private in the textbox using:

```
$('body').append("<div class='keybox'>" + private_key + "</div>");
```

...I am ending up with:

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- MIICdQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAl8wggJbAgEAAoGBALXrNG1e/lENOtdn RX3amQOnhr6KerEXnx86J5txnorGQIZ9lrvSh1Ch7MuqKcZ0oIna8M/MMqZIuLkO oiMir1PsDPS1o+7KYd6g55gSluXCEoKaz9BMYdAqCL/T0B+fNJanwt662MHeSOcS uEgpvMtJIs6ZQEIgWcv6M2ogfAGXAgMBAAECgYAdXYlJ+mKNDNipurbh+O5oQ5uh mFLz0T9TWBzan72a4yO5Uf6J9RL4thq2SZKSwXLErf3fXTPz2ZtP7AfKKigo2ymU YXkVQBjxxCPvPZaET5EjTStOh7wkXYjkKCjjYhL/alpLB8gK1sQwLEe7oYqw+GrK wsuJKXbMDfc9cgYw8QJBAN0mGKARS75wLZ/tfXMeFXZRAMx0aRtVhEV/5C9raXZX FNTMAMUl4UvlxZhV1quszs1aAv52jf32NDkg0fj2Dq8CQQDSlm8ExH5IwE4HQHDh GuynrTUWk3R5zD1VMso97yoY7uTvKb991wPuV6NFAQuC/cCKTzdAU0Z9O44nKR0S jTWZAkAcLt60h3+/pUwrNXjnUs4pZelUJQHAGgXhVYse//FQw4hEFjuC5HDx2zZz U30oI723LeFzzGgMFXRSU3xu3ezBAkAyf+i3l/dAsv0DOCzZjn9Z5mtosoun+ZZr q/Zby9KokAFOaRCGuN00dsescIe2LevSPxTc1Bt/RJzePzm9jSdhAkBQiQFjt4bD y+qDP6T8DAaQqX5UuuNbjnQB5zLQ+ak39bMcc5vQW4oy5UPFeOvXFsrcjrllQkvc +JG7x4bgHAU2 -----END PRIVATE KEY-----

I've looked around so much, and can't figure out how I can get it to work nicely, because the idea being that the user will supply the application with the private key to decrypt information. I thought playing with fonts (e.g. using monospace, or the alignment and justification) would help but nope.

An example tool exists here: https://www.samltool.com/format_privatekey.php but I have no clue how they are going from Private key (which is the nasty one) to the Private Key with header (which is nice formatted one). The output of Private Key with header is exactly what I am after.

Would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: I'm confused. The only difference is that the console respects linebreaks and is in a monospace font. If you use `font-family: monospace; white-space: pre` (or a `<pre>` tag instead of a `<div>`) that should give you a similar appearance, right?

Comment: You have got to be kidding me...was the fix that simple?!? Using <pre> instead of <div> worked beautifully

Comment: Using a fixed-width or [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) will preserve the left and right alignment, using `pre` will preserve the newlines and use a monospaced font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @rickdenhaan who pointed out that simply using `<pre>` instead of  should do the trick!